# C++ objects in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I would like to ask about thread safety in C++ (using POSIX threads with a C++ wrapper for ex.) when a single instance/object of a class is shared between different threads. For example the member methods of this single object of class A would be called within different threads. What should/can I do about thread safety?

```
class A {
    private:

    int n;

    public:

    void increment()
    {
        ++n;
    }

    void decrement()
    {
        --n;
    }
};
```

- Should I protect class member n within increment/decrement methods with a lock or something else? Also static (class variables) members have such a need for lock?
- If a member is immutable, I do not have to worry about it, right?
- Anything that I cannot foreseen now?

In addition to the scenario with a single object within multithreads, what about multiple object with multiple threads? Each thread owns an instance of a class. Anything special other than static (class variables) members?

These are the things in my mind, but I believe this is a large topic and I would be glad if you have good resources and refer previous discussions about that.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: don't try do it by hand. Use a good multithread library like the one from Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html

This article from Intel will give you a good overview: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/multiple-approaches-to-multithreaded-applications/

Answer (score 2):

It's a really large topic and probably it's impossible to complete the topic in this thread.
The golden rule is "You can't read while somebody else is writing."
So if you have an object that share a variable you have to put a lock in the function that access the shared variable.

There are very few cases when this is not true.
The first case is for integer number you can use the atomic function as showed by c-smile, in this case the CPU will use an hardware lock on the cache, so other  cores can't modify the variables.
The second cases are lock free queue, that are  special queue that use the compare and excange function to assure the atomicity of the instruction.

All the other cases are MUST be locked...
the first aproach is to lock everything, this can lead to a lot of problem when more object are involved (ObjA try to read from ObjB but, ObjB is using the variable and also is waiting for ObjC that wait ObjA) Where circular lock can lead to indefinite waiting (deadlock).

A better aproach is to minimize the point where thread share variable.
For example if you have and array of data, and you want to parallelize the computation on the data you can launch two thread and thread one will work only on even index while thread two will work on the odd. The thread are working on the same set of data, but as long the data don't overlap you don't have to use lock. (This is called data parallelization)

The other aproch is to organize the application as a set of "work" (function that run on a thread a produce a result) and make the work communicate only with messages. You only have to implement a thread safe message system and a work sheduler you are done. Or you can use libray like intel TBB.

Both approach don't solve deadlock problem but let you isolate the problem and find bugs more easily. Bugs in multithread are really hard to debug and sometime are also difficoult to find.

So, if you are studing I suggest to start with the thery and start with pThread, then whe you are learned the base move to a more user frendly library like boost or if you are using Gcc 4.6 as compiler the C++0x std::thread

Answer (score 0):

- yes, you should protect the functions with a lock if they are used in a multithreading environment. You can use [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html)
- and yes, immutable members should not be a concern, since a such a member can not be changed once it has been initialized.

Concerning "multiple object with multiple threads".. that depends very much of what you want to do, in some cases you could use a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) which is a mechanism that has a defined number of threads standing by for jobs to come in. But there's no [thread concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) there since each thread does one job.

Answer (score -1):

You have to protect counters. No other options.

On Windows you can do this using these functions:

```
#if defined(PLATFORM_WIN32_GNU)

  typedef long counter_t;
  inline long _inc(counter_t& v)               {    return InterlockedIncrement(&v);  }
  inline long _dec(counter_t& v)               {    return InterlockedDecrement(&v);  }
  inline long _set(counter_t &v, long nv)      {    return InterlockedExchange(&v, nv);  }

#elif defined(WINDOWS) && !defined(_WIN32_WCE) // lets try to keep things for wince simple as much as we can

  typedef volatile long counter_t;
  inline long _inc(counter_t& v)               {    return InterlockedIncrement((LPLONG)&v);  }
  inline long _dec(counter_t& v)               {    return InterlockedDecrement((LPLONG)&v);  }
  inline long _set(counter_t& v, long nv)      {    return InterlockedExchange((LPLONG)&v, nv);  }
```